# Debugging large query in Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging, stored-functions

Can I single-step through the conditions in a relatively complicated SQL query that lives inside a table-valued stored procedure from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: `Debug` and `Step Into F11` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Sam Thanks for this lead. I get "Failed to start the debugger. The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'."

Comment: You need to execute this command to give yourself rights. `GRANT Execute on sys.dbo.sp_enable_sql_debug to 'ME'`. However, you need to be a member of the `sysadmin role` in order to execute that proc.

Comment: check [Link](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/23/debugging-sql-queries-function-amp-stored-procedures-with-sql-management-studio)